# System tray missing in Ubuntu 13.04 and notifications show only an icon

Tags: 13.04, gnome, system-tray

I just installed Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Usually the system tray used to appear at the bottom when I moved my mouse there, but now nothing appears. Also instead of the notification box appearing at the bottom just an icon appears, and then when the mouse is brought near it, it just vanishes.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the installation was corrupted.  Time to go back to stock.

Try this, it usually fixes and reverts any problems I've ever gone through.

```
Sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm unity
```